# Why Marker Manager doesn't work?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, javascript

I would use MarkerManager to group neighboring marker in one, I tested an example but it does not work. Different markers are displayed well, but they are not together when they should. The manager is not working as it should, I do not understand why.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test GMap - MarkerManager</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/src/markermanager.js"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="my-map" style="width:100%;height:700px"></div>
    <script>
        var maCarte = '';
        function initialisation(){
            var centreCarte = new google.maps.LatLng(47.389982, 0.688877);
            var optionsCarte = {
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: centreCarte,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
            maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my-map"), optionsCarte);
            // Create a new instance of the MarkerManager
            var mgr = new MarkerManager(maCarte);
            google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function() {
                console.log('loaded Map');
                // Create marker array
                var markers = [];
                // Loop to create markers and adding them to the MarkerManager
                for(var i = 0; i < 50; i += 0.1) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.389982 + i, 0.688877 + i)});
                    markers.push(marker);
                }
                //var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
                // Add the array to the MarkerManager
                mgr.addMarkers(markers, 8);
                // Refresh the MarkerManager to make the markers appear on the map
                mgr.refresh();
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialisation); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Can someone help me?

thank you very much

Comment: You stand a better chance of getting an answer if you can be more precise about what the problem is, and what you've tried so far to fix it.

Comment: Pretty clear examples here: http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/docs/examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page works for me, but the markers are not immediately visible when the page loads.  This is because of the zoom setting you have on line 34:

```
mgr.addMarkers(markers, 8);
```

if you set that to a lower number (say, 4) the markers will be visible when zoomed further out.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.
My problem is that I want the markers displayed in this manner when the zoom is far: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/examples/google_northamerica_offices.html

Comment: you mean you only want the markers to show during a certain range of zoom?  you can pass a low and high zoom value to the addMarkers method:

    mgr.addMarkers(markers, 4, 6);